# Fade multiple elements - like a carousel, but fading all elements instead of sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, slick.js

I'm trying to create an image carousel style system, which displays multiple images at once; except instead of sliding between those images, the images fade.

So for example, 5 images might be displayed, then after a set period of time (say 3 seconds), they all fade at once to the next 5 images.

I was trying to use Slick Carousel to achieve this, but the behaviour isn't available by default - you can fade one element easily, but as soon as you want to display multiple images, it doesn't work.

Some people have had similar issues, and have experimented with solutions using Slick Carousel, however none of them are quite right.

Here's a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/22e6q2rt/ - showing my progress so far. This sort of works, but the transitions aren't very nice. I'd like a nice crossfade, where one set of images fades out while the next set fades in. Here's the code:

```
$('.multipleslider').slick({ 
dots: false, 
infinite: true, 
speed: 0, 
slidesToShow: 3, 
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 1400,
slidesToScroll: 3, 
cssEase: 'linear' 
});


.slick-slide {
   opacity: .5;
   transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
div.slick-current {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

div.slick-active{
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

I don't mind if this system is a standalone jquery / javascript solution, or uses an existing javascript plugin, such as Slick or Owl Carousel... but none of them seem suitable, and I've hit a wall! Any help would be amazing, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of react-slick with multiple elements almost fadeing and looks similar:

[carousal](https://codepen.io/arshanting/pen/pOKgZz)

```
$('.fade').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  arrows: false,
  speed: 0,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 4, 
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try playing with the timing functions in the slick-slider object. i've changed them for you here

```
$('.multipleslider').slick({ 
dots: false, 
infinite: true, 
speed: 1000, 
slidesToShow: 3, 
autoplay: false,
autoplaySpeed: 1400,
slidesToScroll: 3, 
cssEase: 'ease-in' 
});
```

I changed the autoplay to false and bumped the speed up to 1000, I'm guessing this is in miliseconds. On top of that, you can play with the cssEase to be either ease-in, ease-out, ease, cubic bezier, etc.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for looking into this. Unfortunately this isn't what I'm trying to achieve - I'm aiming for a slow crossfade, no sliding at all. Changing to those settings unfortunately just looks much the same, but sliding as well as the unattractive semi-fade I had previously.